# Square-integrable representations of noncompact groups

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

In Marc Rieffel's paper "Square-integrable Representations of Hilbert Algebras," he establishes (Corollary 5.12) that a nonfinite discrete group has no square-integrable, irreducible representations. Here, we say that a representation $\pi:G\to \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{H})$ is *square-integrable* if there exists a vector $\xi\in\mathcal{H}$ such that the function

$$ x\to \langle \pi(x)\xi,\xi\rangle $$
 is in $L^2(G)$ (where G is assumed locally compact and equipped with Haar measure.)

This relies on the fact that *any* noncompact (locally compact) group has no finite-dimensional, square-integrable representations. Does anyone have a quick proof of this fact? For example, why does $\mathbb{Z}$ itself have no finite-dimensional, square-integrable reperesentations?

Comment: Surely you want to assume $\xi \ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is an answer in Alain Robert's book "Introduction to the Representation Theory of Compact and Locally Compact Groups."